# Div with width:100% and max-width and margins, on resize the right margin is not visible

Tags: html, css

On resize, when the window is smaller than the div, the right margin is not shown. Any idea how to fix it?

Example:

```html
<div style="width:100%;max-width:500px;background-color:red;margin:0 30px 0 30px;">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Use `width:auto` instead of `100%`. 100% makes the margin meaningless- since the div already takes 100% of the space, where is the margin going to go? Block elements however automatically spread to full width, minus the margin... which seems to be what you're after

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the width 100% or set it to auto.

```
<div style="width:auto;max-width:500px;background-color:red;margin:0 30px 0 30px;">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I also had display:inline-block; but I changed to block now. Thanks!